# Why don't we get a smooth ROC curve in CART models

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

I am trying to compare ROC curves obtained from logistic regression and CART model. I found that the ROC curves for logistic regression to be very smooth. This makes sense because the threshold range is continuos between [0,1]. I want to understand why the ROC curve is not smooth for CART models. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Logistic regression fits a continuous function. Trees are discrete. But even logistic regression will produce step-like ROC curves if your data is not smooth-ish.

Comment: I'm nominating this for migration to datascience.stackexchange - it doesn't seem like a programming question.

Comment: Off Topic: migrate to datascience.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

The reason is quite simple - thresholds in decisions trees are crisp, since this are usually efficiently ratios of classes in leaves. If you have N training points there are only N different possible ratios that a leaf can have, and thus (at most) N possible classifications that can be obtained by just moving this one threshold. You can thing about this in a following way, in the end each point is classified when it falls down to some leaf. In this leaf you have K positive and M negatives samples. You classify to positive class according to K/(M+K) > threshold. How many different values can K/(M+K) take? And how many leaves can your tree have? In the end, these numbers are not that big (they are way smaller than N), and thus most of the thresholds simply change nothing. More visually - decision tree splits your input space in large chunks. And once you flip a single threshold (leaf) a big chunk changes class (color) - thus creating big jumps in your ROC curve.

For logistic regression you (nearly) always have all possibilites, since once you trained w, each testing/training point will have different projection (assuming that they are coming from some continuous distribution) < w, x >, thus when you are moving threshold here (1./(1+exp(< w, x >+b)) > threshold) you obtain N+1 possible labelings, since if you visualize your projected points on w it will look like:

```
* *            * * * *    *    *       *      *  *       * *
--------------------------------------------------------------->
<w, x>
```

and depending on the choice of threshod you will classify everything from -inf to threshold to one class and remaining to another (thus creating N+1 possible labelings) which gives you smooth ROC curve.